# when we need use bundle:lock and unlock on rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i rember in old rails there is a freeze ,in rails3 it seems dispared

also i was confused me when need use bundle:lock and unlock?

help someone could give a help

Answer (score 2):

You don't. From `bundle --help`

> ```
> These commands are obsolete and should no longer be used
> o   bundle lock
> o   bundle unlock
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the Bundler documentation](http://gembundler.com/).