# Conflicts in Gemfile.lock while rebasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, bundler, conflict, rebase

What strategies do people have for resolving Gemfile.lock conflicts while rebasing in Git?

I am having to do this a lot in a recent project, and not only is it tedious, it's not always clear how to do the merge.

Comment: This problem happened to me because I was confused about which branch I was on.  The solution was to slap my forehead and switch back to the correct branch and the Gemfile.lock conflict conflict errors went away.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you could relock it on every merge, through a **merge driver** (that I usually use to [always keep the local version of a file during a merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp)).

See "[Auto Merge Gemfile.lock](http://bitfission.com/blog/2010/07/auto-merge-gemfile-lock.html)" from [Will Leinweber](http://bitfission.com/):

> All you have to do is run <del>`bundle lock`</del> (obsolete in Rail3) `bundle install` to get `bundler` to relock then add that and continue your rebase.
>
> First is your `~/.gitconfig` file.
> Here we're going to give it a new merge strategy, one that will just relock the gemfile.
> Add this to the end:

```
[merge "gemfilelock"]
  name = relocks the gemfile.lock
  driver = bundle install
```

> Next up, we have to tell git to use our new strategy for `Gemfile.lock`, and we do that with `gitattributes`.
> You can either put this in `project/.git/info/attributes` or `project/.gitattributes`.

```
Gemfile.lock merge=gemfilelock
```

Comment: according to bundle, bundle lock is obsolete. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410116/when-we-need-use-bundlelock-and-unlock-on-rails3 is there an updated solution to this???

Comment: @rickypai yes, I have updated the answer, following http://bitfission.com/blog/2010/07/auto-merge-gemfile-lock.html#comment-100076083: `bundle install` is the new lock.

Answer (score 4):

Use `git log Gemfile.lock` to find the hash of a previous commit. Then run `git checkout abcde Gemfile.lock` to revert back. Your `bundle install` command should work after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to automatically set up a git repository to use the mentioned merge resolution strategy: https://gist.github.com/itspriddle/5548930

Alternatively, you can use tpope's hookup to do this (and run database migrations) automatically after git pulls: https://github.com/tpope/hookup